use ACEDAO with Visual Studio c++ 2019
I want to do a simple performance experiment of using DAO with C++.  I found this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/cc811599(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN - which seems to indicate I could do something like:
#import <C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\OFFICE14\ACEDAO.DLL> rename( "EOF", "AdoNSEOF" )

_bstr_t bstrConnect = "C:\\temp\\test.accdb";
DAO::_DBEngine* pEngine = NULL;
CoInitialize(NULL);

HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(
    __uuidof(DAO::DBEngine),
    NULL,
    CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
    IID_IDispatch,
    (LPVOID*)&pEngine);

if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && pEngine)
{
    // COM errors are handled by the C++ try/catch block.
    try
    {
        DAO::DatabasePtr pDbPtr = NULL;
        pDbPtr = pEngine->OpenDatabase(bstrConnect);
        ...

However it is failing on the call to OpenDatabase with this error:

Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call. This is usually a result of calling a function declared with one calling convention with a function pointer declared with a different calling convention.

I am admittedly over my head at this point - I did one semester of c++ decades ago.  Research seems to indicate this is a problem with the header files - but I didn't make any header files, Visual Studio auto-created them by simply doing a build with the #import line in place.  Is it still possible to get something like this to work?

It should work. Works fine for me (but my path is more like C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\ACEDAO.DLL and I'm running on VS 2022 and compiling x64). Make sure the loaded object does reside in the dll you point to so headers are consistent with binaries.

@SimonMourier: Thanks for taking a look! Can you give more details?  Do I do CMake, Clang, or mingw?  I tried both VS 2019, 2022, and a 32-bit and 64-bit ACEDAO from both Office14/Office16.  Sometimes I get class not registered.  If I get past that I always get the ESP error above.  Sometimes I get error about cannot open source file ACEDAO.tlh, and if I open the ACEDAO.tli file it generates numerous compile errors.  Certainly is not straightforward.

@SimonMourier: Actually, I just started a brand new project again, did the 32-bit ACEDAO from Office16 and a 64-bit project, pasted in my code and it worked!  Although half my code is underlined in red and intellisense doesn't work, and I don't understand why bitness didn't matter.

#import never played nice in terms of intellisense, what's important is the tlh and tli files are there. Bitness may not matter if the tlb is the same for x86 vs x84
